# How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?

Tags: windows, maven, batch-file

I made a bat file like:

```
mvn clean;
mvn package;
```

but it doesn't work, only the first command is executed.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Use

```
call mvn clean
call mvn package
```

Note that you don't need semicolons in batch files. And the reason why you need to use `call` is that `mvn` itself is a batch file and batch files need to call each other with `call`, otherwise control does not return to the caller.

If you want subsequent commands to echo to the command line (show in batch output), you must also do `echo on` after the `call mvn` is done (on the next line). This is because `mvn` turns echo off and doesn't turn it back on.

Comment: same with `gradle`

Comment: In addition, Maven has an option for batch script : `-B` ou `--batch-mode` to "Run in non-interactive (batch) mode (disables output color)"

Answer (score 31):

Joey's answer is great, but maybe a more complete code example will help anyone else like me who's also figuring out a similar problem of building multiple maven projects from a batch file in Windows:

```
REM maven itself uses a batch file so each mvn must be preceded by "call"
REM the -f flag specifies where the pom.xml is found for the project
REM mvn install will save the target output to %userprofile%\.m2\repository ...

call mvn install -f c:\Users\John\workspace\PropertiesReader\pom.xml

call mvn install -f c:\Users\John\workspace\PropertiesWriter\pom.xml
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also have the following one-liner:

```
call mvn clean package
```

Comment: Still, they should use `call` so that anything they write after the `mvn` command will run.

Answer (score 12):

The observed bahaviour comes from the time of MS-DOS 1.0 and it is kept for compatibility reasons. As a solution you shall use Windows **call** function in the following way:

```
call mvn clean
call mvn package
```

The "call" executes one batch program from another and interprets it as subroutine.

Answer (score 10):

I have more projects to run, I created such bat this:

```
@echo off
SET DEVELOPMENT_HOME=C:\Projects

cd %DEVELOPMENT_HOME%\Project1\
call mvn clean install

cd %DEVELOPMENT_HOME%\Project2\
call mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 8):

Use 'call' when you want to invoke another batch file in the parent file ,so that control will  be returned to the parent batch file and it will continue execution.

e.g call mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

```
Use these commands in batch file to run ur script. Keep your batch file where 
you pom.xml file is housed

set ProjectPath=C:\TetonWorkSpace\PeriodicApplicationCheck
cd %ProjectPath%
mvn clean test -Dxmlfile=Smoke.xml
pause

To Create a Task in Task scheduler:
1. Follow steps as prescribed to create task
2. In the action tab, just place the path of ur batch file as shown below
    C:\TetonWorkSpace\PeriodicApplicationCheck\testng.bat
3. You can ignore the rest two options like Add Argument and Start in. Use it 
   only when there are certain conditions to be used without which the script 
    becomes dysfunctional.
```

[image: Placing path of the batch file in Action Tab.]

Answer (score -1):

we can use the following to build a maven and pass it to any unix folder for development purpose

```
SET projectName=commonutil
cd %gitpath%\%projectName%
call mvn clean install -DskipTests=true %password%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (Echo No error found) ELSE goto exitdoor 
SET jarpath="%gitpath%\%projectName%\target\%projectName%-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
copy /Y %jarpath% "%libpath%"
scpg3 %jarpath% %ssh_profile_name%@%hostname%:%dev_lib_folder_name%
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

call `mvn clean package`

```
sample
------
echo %test%
cd %test%\ManaulActionAddNotes-test
call mvn clean
cd %test%\restAuthentication-test
call mvn clean
```

Comment: Where is here more information than in the other answers? It looks for me like a duplicate of the accepted (9 year old) answer