# Calling Gradle from .bat causes batch execution to stop

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, command-line, gradle

I'm automating the publication of my Android app and I'm using **Gradle**, great utility!

Just a problem, consider this .bat file (under Windows 7):

```
:: assemble the project
gradle assemble -Pprofile_name=%profile_name% -p%destination_dir%

::copy apk to repository
copy "D:\compile\myapp\build\apk\*.apk" "d:\build_repository"
```

Well the copy command is never executed, never. It seems that the execution stops after calling gradle utility. Any idea?

The build within Gradle has **ends with success** and no error at all...

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question (it may not be Gradle specific), but I do recommend to do the copying with Gradle.

Comment: Do you have a nice link that explains how to copy the output apk to a folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573062/how-to-execute-more-than-one-maven-command-in-bat-file)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into this very same problem, but for a webapp. Gradle isn't necessarily the issue, but how you are invoking it. As explained in this post,

[How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573062/execute-more-than-one-maven-command-in-bat-file)

because gradle is a batch file itself, it completes execution and doesn't return control back to your batch file. Use the same 'call' strategy and everything should work.
Like so for your original post,

```
call gradle assemble -Pprofile_name=%profile_name% -p%destination_dir%

::copy apk to repository
copy "D:\compile\myapp\build\apk\*.apk" "d:\build_repository"
```

Comment: Impressively simple, you did it!

Answer (score -1):

If you are on ionic/cordova and batch execution is stopping after ionic cordova build --release android use call before

> call ionic cordova build --release android