# Batch script stops after check

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this batch script, that chacks if git and maven are available.

```
@echo off
git --version >nul 2>&1 && ( 
        echo [OK] Git check OK
    ) || ( 
        echo [Error] Git not available!
        EXIT /B 2
    )
mvn --version >nul 2>&1 && ( 
        echo [OK] Maven check OK 
    ) || ( 
        echo [Error] Maven not available! 
        EXIT /B 2
    )

echo Not printed!
```

The problem is that the script stops after the check for maven. It prints:

```
[OK] Git check OK
[OK] Maven check OK
```

and the last echo is skipped.

Comment: I don't have git or mvn, but if I try with `dir`, the output is fine. Which OS is it exactly?

Comment: Are `git` and `mvn` both executables, or is any a batch file? for batch files, precede `call`...

Comment: @ThomasWeller Windows 10. It works for other commands. Looks like a `mvn` specific issue.

Comment: @aschipfl mvn was batch file. That's it. I changed the script to `call mvn` and now it works. If you write it as and answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: [keiv-fly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37976622/5047996) was too quick...

Comment: I wish the developers would stop writing batch files as they're suboptimal. It's easy enough to distribute an executable that calls the Java runtime to execute Maven, so why write a batch file and introduce these problems in the first place?

Comment: `mvn`  is a bat file so you need `call mvn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573062/how-to-execute-more-than-one-maven-command-in-bat-file) mvn should be prepended with call because it is a batch file itself.

```
@echo off
git --version >nul 2>&1 && ( 
        echo [OK] Git check OK
    ) || ( 
        echo [Error] Git not available!
        EXIT /B 2
    )
call mvn --version >nul 2>&1 && ( 
        echo [OK] Maven check OK 
    ) || ( 
        echo [Error] Maven not available! 
        EXIT /B 2
    )

echo Not printed!
```